# How can I repair my old tube TV safely?

Tags: high-voltage, tv, tube

I got an old Nokia tube television from my grandmother. I tested it, but there is **no picture**. I can hear the audio. The filament is not glowing. I am studying EE, but there I only dealt with low voltage devices like transistors and their combinations.
Do you have any idea where the error could be? What should I check? Is there any safety regulation I should care about (I heard that these old TVs emit X-rays.)? What about the danger of implosion?

Thank you for your hints!

Comment: It's a shame if modern EE programs don't even teach the basics of vacuum tube electronics, even if only to give historical perspective. If you are interested in this in terms of broadening your understanding of your field, you might check out your local amateur radio club. There are bound to be some old timers who would lend you a copy of their 1956 Radio Amateur's Handbook or RCA Receiving Tube Manual. However, given that your TV is a Nokia, it is probably mostly solid state. Nokia did not get into electronics before sometime in the 1960's, consumer electronics probably much later.

Comment: do you have any kind of schematics on the tv? if you don't the odds are really bad...

Comment: @mickeyf, he's not talking about vacuum tubes, I don't believe. I think he's talking about a picture tube.

Comment: Don't mess with it if you aren't sure. CRT's are high value farad capacitors in disguise and will very seriously shock the crap out of you. They can hold a charge for over a week or more.  A old 26" CRT packed a wallop of 26.5Kv...nuff said . As for implosion risk if you snap the neck you risk exposure to things like phosphorus which I believe will burn you as well along with exposure to a lot of toxic stuff.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. It's not worth it. Tube TVs are so old our local Goodwill won't even take them.

You shouldn't. There are dangerous high voltages. This isn't a project to start with.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a little more specific as to which model you're dealing with.

You also need to be *really* careful.

If this tube TV uses vacuum tubes on its main circuit board, troubleshooting can be as easy as identifying blown tubes, sourcing replacements and plugging them in.

If this is a solid-state TV with only the picture tube as a tube, debugging may will be difficult without a schematic. Try and find a schematic or a service manual.

My gut tells me that the HV flyback power supply has failed. This is dangerous territory. The tube requires an extremely high voltage to operate (in excess of 15 kV in many TVs). Messing around with this voltage can easily kill you. The residual charge that can be left on the HV tube connection can linger for weeks and can be harmful. Always assume the tube is charged, and take measures to discharge it before touching anything.

If you're not comfortable with the idea of HV, don't risk a repair. Recycle the set and get something a little more modern.

Answer (score 1):

To add another voice to the existing answers:  frankly speaking, if you're asking these fundamental questions, I urge you to reconsider "poking around" inside this device.

In most CRT based TVs from the 80's foward, the power supply has a "hot-ground" and, if you're not *very* careful, you just might kill yourself.

If you insist on going forward, at the very least, make sure to use an isolation transformer to remove the danger from the hot-ground.

But really, you shouldn't be inside the set *at all* if you're asking these questions.

Answer (score -1):

Find a ham radio operator in the area who has had a license since about 1970 and has experience with high voltage circuits (some of the KW amplifiers get up to about 3KV.) There are special tools for dissipating the high voltage that allow you to access the components. The value of this device is primarily that it shows how the technology works. If you want it for anything else I have to agree with those who say that even Good Will would not want it. You will also likely need a converter box as anything this old will not receive digital signals of today.

Since you mention that you did not see the glowing of filaments but do hear audio, my assumption is the TV is a hybrid (partially solid-state and partially tube) which would likely mean it was made after about 1970. From there I would be guessing other than to repeat what others have said about the need to be careful about the high voltage and implosion risk (mainly if you try to replace the picture tube) but there is a lot to be said for understanding how different technologies work.